# what type of encoding is this "Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, encoding, windows-server-2003, iconv, magmi

I am trying to export the out put of `mssql` query which must use `utf` (utf-16 I suppose) encoding according to [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) I am using `-W -u`
functions with `sqlcmd`. 
 Ä is converted to character z (with 2 dots or something like ^ inverted) by default, and lists it as `ansi` character set. 
when I try to use notepad++ to convert this `utf` file to `utf-8` shows me with some strange highlighted characters `(x8E)` for `Ä`, and some other for other characters like `x86` and `x94` does not matter what ever encoding I use as default in Nottepad++.

When I transfered the file to a `Ubuntu 12.04` machine and using `file` command says that its

> user@user:~/Desktop/enc
>   oding/checkencoding$ file
>   convertit4.csv  convertit4.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII English
>   text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
>
> user@user:~/Desktop/encoding/checkencoding$ chardet
>   convertit4.csv  convertit4.csv: ISO-8859-2 (confidence: 0.77)
>   I am confused what kind of encoding it uses. 
>   the purpose is to convert it to `utf-8` encoding without any errors to upload it to [`magmi` importer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki).

note: I am using this command to remove the underline after the headers `type c:\outfiles\convertit1.temp | findstr /r /v "^\-[;\-]*$" > c:\outfiles\convertit4.csv` hope this line of codes is not the problem.

I hope the information are complete to solve this issue, If any more information needed, please let me know, 
Regards.

Comment: Are you using the `-o` option? `-u` has no effect without it.

Comment: @Neil          yes, I am using `-o` as well and getting it on a CSV format.

Comment: I don't think `FINDSTR` supports Unicode, sorry.

Comment: @Neil           Thanks you for your response.I was able to remove dashed lines below the headers of output file. Does not this mean `FINDSTR` supports Unicode? OR other way around would be simply output of `sqlcmd` is not in Unicode encoding. Struggling to solve this issue.

Comment: @Neil Yes it seems that `FINDSTR` doesn't support `unicode`. This command was converting the string to strange sets.

Answer (score 2):

Try the -f option as in 
http://www.yaldex.com/sql_server_tutorial_3/ch06lev1sec1.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I went through that and now my collation having `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` how do I get the value of code page for Swedish language? Looked around but seems difficult to figure out every one talking about the `code point` but not the `code page`. According to the link you provided needs kind of code page.